# preg_replace of annonying html tags and backslash php

Tags: php, html, preg-replace

i need help with preg replace and figure it
i have content like

```
<a href=\http://www.example.com\ target=\_blank\ title=\Cleo's Vip Room\>
<img src=\linkurl.tld\ />
<table style=\font-family:Arial, sans-serif;\ border=\0\ cellspacing=\0\ cellpadding=\0\ align=\center\>
```

and there are a lot all uses \ instead of "
i want to remove them all and keep only URLs and images to something like [URL]url.tld[/URL] and [img]image source [/img] to use for forums bbcode

help please

Comment: you put 4 \\\\ these are counted from my content ?

Comment: Those will select a single `\\` (backslash) for replacement.

Comment: Thanks preg replace is really a big science however i want to formate my content for forums so updating it with " will not help also i want to remove all other tags like <table style properties>content</table> so on with td etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$html = "<a href=\http://www.example.com\ target=\_blank\ title=\Cleo's Vip Room\>
<img src=\linkurl.tld\ />
<table style=\font-family:Arial, sans-serif;\ border=\0\ cellspacing=\0\ cellpadding=\0\ align=\center\>";

$newHtml = preg_replace('/\\\\/', '"', $html);

echo $newHtml;
```